# How to change already created folder/directory security permission using Windows API C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, directory

I have to change directory permission of already created directory. If the directory does not exists,I am able to create new directory using CreateDirectoryEx with given security access attributes,however when the directory already exists ,I have to change security access attributes of directory
For ex:Admin -Full access
User=read access

First check if directory exists,if directory exists change the security attributes

Comment: the best call `SetKernelObjectSecurity` on file handle. possible and call `SetNamedSecurityInfo` if you still not open file

Comment: really you need call `NtCreateFile` with `FILE_OPEN_IF` (open existing or create new) and check iosb.Information - `FILE_CREATED` or `FILE_OPENED`. and then call `SetKernelObjectSecurity` on file handle

Comment: [SetKernelObjectSecurity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-setkernelobjectsecurity): *"Note: This function should not be used when setting a security descriptor on file system objects. Instead, use the [SetSecurityInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-setsecurityinfo) or [SetNamedSecurityInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-setnamedsecurityinfow) functions."*

Comment: @IInspectable I already have SecurityAttributes Object SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,is there any API I wanted to modify the directory permission similarly when we create new directory using CreateDirectoryEx(directoryname,SecurityAttributeS)

Comment: @IInspectable - and why ?! this api excellent work with files too. and really no another way set sd on file (this or direct call `NtSetSecurityObject`). the `SetSecurityInfo` of course internally call `SetKernelObjectSecurity` (or `NtSetSecurityObject`). so msdn and your note is wrong

Comment: @ra10 - *I already have SecurityAttributes Object SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES* so you already have pointer to `PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR` - so very simply call `SetKernelObjectSecurity` with it\

Comment: @RbMm Sry I dont have handle,is there anything we can overrwrite security permssion on the directory? For example CreateNewDirectoryEx(directoryname,SecurityAttributesobject)

Comment: *Sry I dont have handle* - and in what problem open/create it ? and you want do this only for existing folder or make open_if logic (open if exist, create if not exist) ? and how i say - use `SetKernelObjectSecurity`

Comment: @RbMm I want to first check if directory exists,if directory exists have to change the folder permission,can you share sample code

Comment: @ra10 - yes, can. but please say - *check if directory exists* - if directory not exist - what you want do in this case ? create new ? or only set security on existing and not create new ? and never need check - need simply open (or create).

Comment: @RbMm If directory does not exist create new directory with a pointer to  SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure

Comment: @ra10 - ok. i understand. no any problem in such task

Comment: @IInspectable Is it possible to pass  SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES object to SetNamedSecurityInfo function

Comment: @rbm I quoted the documented contract. The contract specifies the supported uses of this API. In this case it also calls out a use case that's outside its supported specification. Contracts aren't subject to negotiations. Calling them *"wrong"* is exhibiting denial of reality.

Comment: @rbm Ok, then, that's easy to prove: Go ahead, click the [Edit](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sdk-api/blob/docs/sdk-api-src/content/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-setkernelobjectsecurity.md) link at the top right corner of the documentation, remove the content you believe to be *"wrong and bug or lie"*, prepare a pull request, and have Microsoft accept it. Until that has happened, let's just err on the side of safety and assume you are wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable Can u guide me on how to resolve this issue

Comment: @ra10 - no any issue at all here

Comment: @RbMm Can u also help?

Comment: @IInspectable - if want may be you can explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62390785/6401656)  **why** `SetKernelObjectSecurity` function should not be used when setting a security descriptor on file system objects. not - *can not be used* but *should not be used*. without explain **why** - this is nothing

Comment: @rbm Why? Because the contract tells you not to. Not sure what else there is to add.

Comment: @IInspectable - no it doesn’t explain anything. maybe this is enough for you and you are not interested - it is said not to do and you are not doing. but not enough for me. I demand a logical explanation why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to change directory permisison using this article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/modifying-the-acls-of-an-object-in-c--

Answer (score 0):

for set security on a kernel object need use [`NtSetSecurityObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntsetsecurityobject) or [`SetKernelObjectSecurity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-setkernelobjectsecurity) (which is very thin shell over `NtSetSecurityObject`) especially if you already have object handle with `WRITE_DAC` and `WRITE_OWNER` if you want set also [`LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/security-information).

need understand that no any another way for set security on object - any another api like [`SetSecurityInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-setsecurityinfo) or [`SetNamedSecurityInfoW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-setnamedsecurityinfow) anyway internal call `SetKernelObjectSecurity` or `NtSetSecurityObject`.

if we need *open_if* logic - create new folder if it yet not exist or open if it already exist - need use or [`NtCreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwcreatefile) with `FILE_OPEN_IF` disposition. then need look for *Information* member of `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` - are it `FILE_OPENED` or `FILE_CREATED`. and if `FILE_OPENED` call `NtSetSecurityObject` because in this case *SecurityDescriptor* will be ignored in call `NtCreateFile`. otherwise we set *SecurityDescriptor* already inside `NtCreateFile`. code can be next:

```
NTSTATUS CreateFolderWithSD(PCWSTR lpNewDirectory, PSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES psa)
{
    UNICODE_STRING ObjectName;

    NTSTATUS status = RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U_WithStatus(lpNewDirectory, &ObjectName, 0, 0);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;

        OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, &ObjectName, 0, psa->lpSecurityDescriptor };

        status = NtCreateFile(&oa.RootDirectory, WRITE_DAC|WRITE_OWNER, &oa, &iosb, 0,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_OPEN_IF, 
            FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE, 0, 0);

        RtlFreeUnicodeString(&ObjectName);

        if (0 <= status)
        {
            switch (iosb.Information)
            {
            case FILE_OPENED:
                status = NtSetSecurityObject(oa.RootDirectory, 
                    DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION|LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, oa.SecurityDescriptor);
            case FILE_CREATED:
                break;
            default: __debugbreak();
            }

            NtClose(oa.RootDirectory);
        }
    }

    return status;
}

void TestNF(PCWSTR lpNewDirectory)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(sa) };

    if (ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(
        L"D:P(A;;FA;;;SY)(A;;FA;;;BA)(A;;FRFX;;;BU)S:(ML;;NWNX;;;HI)",
        SDDL_REVISION_1, &sa.lpSecurityDescriptor, 0))
    {
        CreateFolderWithSD(lpNewDirectory, &sa);
        LocalFree(sa.lpSecurityDescriptor);
    }
}
```

---

at the msdn page for [SetKernelObjectSecurity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-setkernelobjectsecurity) function exist next note

> **Note**  This function should not be used when setting a security descriptor on file system objects. Instead, use the
>   **SetSecurityInfo** or **SetNamedSecurityInfo** functions.

now my note on this note - why **should not be used** ? (and this is not mean can not be used - can of course). i not view any reason or explain for this. and in any case this api **will be used** when we set security on file - direct or indirect. so think need ignore this note, which nothing explain.

---

also note about use of native api - this is both kernel and user mode api (not only kernel as many think), and use it so easy (or hard) like any another api. no any different (simply use *ntdllp.lib* or *ntdll.lib*) . i use `NtCreateFile` because any win 32 api not provide such functional - open_if logic on folder and return result - are file actually opened or created. `CreateFileW` can not create folder, also even for files - despite option `OPEN_ALWAYS` exist (equ for `FILE_OPEN_IF`) the api not return information are `FILE_OPENED` or `FILE_CREATED` - it simply drop it. the `CreateDirectory` at all have no *open_if* logic - it fail with `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` if the specified directory already exists. so really `NtCreateFile` have the best and no analog functional here because exactly it and used. the `NtSetSecurityObject` used but not `SetKernelObjectSecurity` for give the same error type (`NTSTATUS`) like and `NtCreateFile`

Comment: `SetKernelObjectSecurity` (i.e. `NtSetSecurityObject`) normally shouldn't be used to set the security on a directory because it doesn't propagate inheritable ACEs in the filesystem tree. `SetSecurityInfo` is implemented by ntmarta.dll, which supports propagating inheritable ACEs (e.g. `ntmarta!MartaManualPropagation`, `ntmarta!MartaUpdateTree`).

Comment: @ErykSun - this is already question how build security descriptor. and want we really have inherited ACE or not. anyway finally `SetKernelObjectSecurity` (i.e. `NtSetSecurityObject`) will be called. may be with internal modified DACL list

Comment: The question wants to modify/add ACEs to an existing directory.  Using `SetKernelObjectSecurity` for this task is generally wrong. If any of the new ACEs are inheritable, or an inheritable ACE is being removed, then this update must be propagated in the tree manually, which `SetSecurityInfo` implements for us.

Comment: Also, a couple points of clarification. `CreateFileW` supports the open status information for its `CREATE_ALWAYS` and `OPEN_ALWAYS` dispositions by setting the thread's last error to `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` if the open status info is `FILE_OVERWRITTEN` or `FILE_OPENED`.

Comment: `CreateFileW` can create a directory in two ways. The general way, which is not documented and doesn't support `OPEN_ALWAYS`: use `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` , `FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS`, and `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` with the `CREATE_NEW` disposition. The other way is documented and supports `OPEN_ALWAYS`, but it requires a filesystem that supports streams (e.g. NTFS). Use the "$INDEX_ALLOCATION" stream type when opening, e.g. "dirname::$INDEX_ALLOCATION". This way doesn't even require backup semantics.

Comment: @ErykSun - however for my look much more simply and clear way call `NtCreateFile` here. and i not understand why most so afraid use api exported from ntdll. even well documented. about `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` - yes, my mistake, forget about notification in this way. very not native for me. i at all not like api which set error status in teb instead return error code direct

Comment: I'm not defending WinAPI. It's crufty and badly 'designed' (scare quotes because it's more like evolution by random drift and accretion). However, I don't support using NTAPI. It's designed better, but it's also clunky and awkward to use. It was meant for implementing subsystems, not as a convenient API. It's also intentionally undocumented in parts. I'd prefer a supported, well-documented, simple, and consistent API that's layered over NTAPI as an alternative to WinAPI, especially for language runtime designers (e.g. CPython). But I'm stuck with WinAPI.